# Magento 2 Checkout Error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCacheKey' of null

Tags: magento2, checkout, onestepcheckout, magento-2.2.5

I have an issue on the checkout page and we are getting the below error on the console. It looks like the address object is not loaded correctly on the quote object and we are getting a different error each time.

This issue comes randomly and mostly when the user redirects to the live payment method and comes back to the checkout page after canceling payment.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCacheKey' of null
    at UiClass.<anonymous> (billing-address.js:95)
    at Function.notifySubscribers (knockout.js:1103)
    at Function.observable.valueHasMutated (knockout.js:1300)
    at Object.observable [as billingAddress] (knockout.js:1285)
    at select-billing-address.js:26
    at UiClass.paramsHandler (billingfields.js:350)
    at UiClass.<anonymous> (ajax.js:169)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (underscore.js:150)
    at UiClass.collectParams (ajax.js:168)
    at UiClass.passPayload (ajax.js:64)
```

Comment: did you get any solution on this?

Comment: @Deeps Have get fixed this issue. I have faced same issue. Please share your solution here so we can help. – Kirti Nariya 8 mins ago