# magento 2.3.2: checkout Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCacheKey' of null

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento2.3.2, billing-address

I have an issue on checkout page and we are getting below error on console. It looks like address object is not loaded correctly on quote object and we are getting different error each time.

i know here someone asked this [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/240445/68695) but nothing find proper solution

```
billing-address.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCacheKey' of null
    at UiClass.<anonymous> (billing-address.min.js:1)
    at Function.notifySubscribers (knockout.min.js:133)
    at Function.valueHasMutated (knockout.min.js:149)
    at Object.observable [as billingAddress] (knockout.min.js:143)
    at select-billing-address.min.js:2
    at checkout-data-resolver.min.js:14
    at Function._.some._.any (underscore.min.js:15)
    at Function.some (observable_array.min.js:4)
    at Object.applyBillingAddress (checkout-data-resolver.min.js:14)
    at Object.resolveBillingAddress (checkout-data-resolver.min.js:13)
```

[image: ut]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: did you get any solution on this?

Comment: @IndranilMaity still nothing...

Comment: Try below comment, I've just posted.

Comment: @RakeshDonga Have got fixed this issue. I have faced same issue. Please share your solution here so we can help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

Change the line 86 of the following file:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/billing-address.js

It should be changed from

```
if (quote.isVirtual()) {
```

to

```
if (quote.isVirtual() || !quote.shippingAddress()) {
```

Run these commends after making the above change.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Now check on the site, Hope it will work!

Please note that you can override this file in your custom module or extension. If you don't want to make these changes on Magento core file.

Ref : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/24131

Comment: How can fix this issue using create mixins js in custom module ?